# Finding interior angle of two lines and describing its relationship with distance

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Our team has been on this question for a good few days, but unfortunately, we are far from being mathematicians and need a little guidance! We are trying to find $\phi$ using two points and two angles drawn in the picture. For extra brownie points,  explain what relationship the distance $l$ and $\phi$ have in common.

[image]

This question is a small (but important) obstacle in our way of optimizing a search method we need for our project. Therefore any information to the solution will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you know $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ then $\phi= \theta_1-\theta_2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the points $A$ and $B$, and the third point $C$ --- the one you're looking for. Let $v$ and $w$ be unit vectors in the direction from $A$ to $C$ and from $B$ to $C$ respectively, i.e.,

$$
v = (\sin \theta_1, \cos \theta_1)\\
w = (\sin \theta_2, \cos \theta_2)
$$

Then we have
$$
C = A + tv \\
C = B + sw
$$
for some numbers $t$ and $s$, hence
$$
A + tv = B + sw
$$
Taking a dot product with the vector $v' = (-\cos \theta_1, \sin \theta_1)$, which is $v$ rotated 90 degrees counterclockwise, we get
$$
A\cdot v' + t v \cdot v' = B\cdot v' + s w \cdot v'
$$
Since $v \cdot v' = 0$, we get
$$
\frac{(A-B) \cdot v'}{w \cdot v'} = s 
$$
and from this, you can determine $C$.

..and now I realize that all you wanted was $\phi$, which is $\theta_1 - \theta_2$, as @EmilioNovati observed in the comments. But since you'll probably want to work out some more details as well, I'm keeping what follows:

Unwinding all that,

\begin{align}
C 
&= B + sw \\
&= (x_2, y_2) + \frac{(A-B) \cdot v'}{w \cdot v'} w\\
&= (x_2, y_2) + \frac{(x_1 - x_2, y_1 - y_2) \cdot (-\cos \theta_1, \sin \theta_1)}{w \cdot v'} w\\
&= (x_2, y_2) + \frac{(-\cos \theta_1)(x_1 - x_2) + (\sin \theta_1)( y_1 - y_2)}{w \cdot v'} w\\
&= (x_2, y_2) + \frac{(-\cos \theta_1)(x_1 - x_2) + (\sin \theta_1)( y_1 - y_2)}{(\sin \theta_2)(-\cos \theta_1) + (\cos \theta_2)(\sin \theta_1)} w\\
&= (x_2, y_2) + \frac{(-\cos \theta_1)(x_1 - x_2) + (\sin \theta_1)( y_1 - y_2)}{(\sin \theta_2)(-\cos \theta_1) + (\cos \theta_2)(\sin \theta_1)}  (\sin \theta_2, \cos \theta_2)\\
&= (x_2, y_2) + \frac{(-\cos \theta_1)(x_1 - x_2) + (\sin \theta_1)( y_1 - y_2)}{\sin (\theta_1 - \theta_2)}  (\sin \theta_2, \cos \theta_2)
\end{align}

The relationship between $\phi$ and $\ell$ is that if $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ are held constant, and so is the direction from $A$ to $B$ (i.e., the direction of the dotted line), then $\phi$ remains constant even though $\ell$ changes. I'm not sure if this is what you meant, but it's the only relation I can think of.

Comment: THANK YOU! The explanation was clear and really helped. You went above and beyond.